# how to get the size of the SIM card memory?

Tags: android, sim-card

I'd like to know how to get the size of SIM card memory and how much of the memory has been used.

Comment: From my point of view I guess there is no way because it is standardized what can be stored there and how to access it. Because sim cards are sold only by telecom providers, aren't they?

Comment: You need additional hardware. It's a some smart [card reader](http://sim-reader.com/) and a program that can read and parse the data for you.